# Should we delete these superfluous tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Both [hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [projects](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projects) are more or less useless IMO. Almost everything we do is hardware, and concern a project of some kind. Tags should help you to find a particular question. What's the use if there are 1000 questions and looking up [hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) questions would return 950 hits?

So I propose to delete them.

**edit**
Let's throw in [circuit-design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-design) as well. Er, by "in" I mean "out". You know what I mean. :-)

Comment: Some of my favorite tags are [tag:voltage] and [tag:current].

Comment: [tag:device] [tag:parts] [tag:components] anyone?

Comment: Sounds like more meta questions to ask for burninate @W5VO.

Comment: Same for your @jippie

Answer (score 2):

Deleted. Please take a few minutes to [clean up the questions that are now untagged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. We'll have a look at the orphans.

Comment: @stevenvh and you will probably find some questions that just dont belong if that is the only tag they got.